# Call custom dialog in Adapter class

Tags: android, dialog, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have created a simple `Custom dialog` class and I want to display it after clicking on a row in `RecycleView`.
My dialog class looks:

```
public class AddToQueueDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

 Activity mActivity;
private TextView textView1;
private TextView textView2;
private Button save;

public AddToQueueDialog(Activity activity){
    super(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_to_queue);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == save.getId()){
            Log.d("save", "save");
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm wondering how to properly call in `adapter` of `RecycleView` which looks:
(piece)

```
   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {       
        public ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView, List<WashLocation> washLocations) {
            super(itemView);
            this.context = context;
            info = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            favorite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToFav);
            favorite.setOnClickListener(this);
            info.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.washLocations = washLocations;
            dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == info.getId()){
                AddToQueueDialog addToQueueDialog = new AddToQueueDialog(MapsActivity.this);
                addToQueueDialog.show();
            }
```

In my `Custom dialog` class I need an `Activity` in arg as a constructor but I don't know which `Activity` should I pass there in `Adapter` class

Comment: Better call dialog from fragment/activity through interface callback

Comment: Why? Could you post an example?

Comment: @bielas you need to pass instance of currently running activity 
AddToQueueDialog addToQueueDialog = new AddToQueueDialog((Activity)context);
                addToQueueDialog.show();

Comment: @user3333848 yes I know but the question is which exactly Activity should I pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the `context` of your current `Activity`  to your `Adapter` class and use it when you are creating an instance of `AddToQueueDialog`.

**For example:**

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context mContext;

    // Views
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    // Values
    List<Recipe> mRecipeList;

    // Adapter
    RecipeAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = this;

        // Views
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        .................
        ..........................

        // Values
        mRecipeList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();

        // Adapter
        mAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(mContext, mRecipeList);

        // Set adapter to RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        .................
        ..........................
   }
}
```

**`RecipeAdapter.java`**

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // List
    List<Recipe> mRecipeList;

    public GroupListAdapter(Context context, List<Recipe> listRecipe) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mRecipeList = listRecipe;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    .....................
    ...............................

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {       

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            info = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            favorite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToFav);

            favorite.setOnClickListener(this);
            info.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == info.getId()){
                AddToQueueDialog addToQueueDialog = new AddToQueueDialog(mContext);
                addToQueueDialog.show();
            }
       }
    }

    ............
    ......................
}
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

  // set this field through setter or constructor
  private OnClickListener mMyOnClickListener;

  ...

  void onBindViewHolder(..., VH viewHolder) {
    viewHolder.rootView.setOnClickListener(() -> {
       if (mOnClickListener != null) {
          mOnClickListener.onClick();
       }
     });
  }

  static class VH extends ViewHolder {
    View rootView;

    VH(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      rootView = itemView;
    }
  }
}

class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ...

  void setUpRecyclerView(){
    ...
    adapter.setMyOnClickListener(() -> {
       new Dialog(MainActivity.this).show();
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for code, was writing from the iPad. You can create your own interface with method with params, pass any params into that interface method from adapter and handle them in Activity or just trigger an event like in my example

Comment: Well I think it won't match to my example. In my activity class I have some logic connected to google maps. In the second class I have an implementation of RecycleView and Adapter. So then I would like to have an example with different class - one for activity and the second for RecycleView and Adapter. Would you be so kind and create an example of the describe above?

Comment: then what is the problem with @AlexanderGoncharenko 's solution

Comment: @bielas, I've already done, just try to understand this example