# Error in AlertDialog in adapter class

Tags: android, listview

I have this code that is called on an onclick of a adapter...

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);
        builder.setMessage("Disconnect from Instagram?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            //do something
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                mApp.resetAccessToken();
                                // btnConnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                // tvSummary.setText("Not connected");
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

When I run this code I get an error on the first line of code. This one...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like the context you are passing to AlertDialog.Builder is null.

Comment: what exactly is your context variable? Are you using that code from a `Fragment` or `Activity`

Comment: How do I set the context?

Comment: Which line causes the error? Where do you declare and initialize `context`?

Answer (score 1):

the 'context'  must be the type  of activity

Comment: I agree with this answer. The reason why this will work is because activity is a themed context. If you're using the application context, you will recreate the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first line to this:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this).create();
```

Also, remove this line at the bottom:

```
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

If that doesn't work, post the code in the adapter where this code is called.

If you are inside a fragment use this one:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
```

Comment: I edited the answer. No, you want to keep that where you have it

Comment: If i make context = YourClassname.This... I get it underlined in red and it says I can't do that.

Comment: It should be the name of the Activity you are working in. It is your ActivityName.this

Comment: I am it says it can't be added in bulider

Comment: It might bring an error because this is just the adapter class for the main class.

Comment: Look at your adapter to see what context you are passing it. It should be getting 'this' from your Activity. When you set your adapter, what context do you put in the args?

Comment: Look at this answer. He passes the context to his non-activity AdapterClass and calls his dialog. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810106/call-custom-dialog-in-adapter-class

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext())
            .setMessage("Do you really want to delete this size")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
}
```